# Condition for collinearity of points?

Tags: geometry, vectors

Under which of the following conditions will the points $A, B, C$  with position vectors $\vec a$, $\vec b$ and $\vec c$ respectively be collinear?

(a) $\vec c-\vec a = 2(\vec b-\vec a)$

(b) $|\vec c-\vec a|=2|\vec b-\vec a|$

(c) $\vec a=2(\vec b+\vec c)$

(d) $2\vec a+\vec b=\vec c$

(e) $3\vec a-2(\vec b+\vec c)=\vec 0$

**My Try**

Since $(a)$ yields $\vec {AC}=\lambda \vec {AB}$, it is definitely collinear.

Furthermore I know that magnitude does not affect collinearity. I'm stuck determining $(c), (d), (e)$. Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the collinearity $\vec {AC}=\lambda \vec {AB}$ is equivalent to the vector equation 
$$ \vec c = \lambda \vec b + (1-\lambda )\vec a$$

where $\lambda $ is non-zero. Then, verify that $(c), (d), (e)$ do not satisfy the equation above.

Comment: Highly appreciated!